# Disabling auto-commit in NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbctemplate, autocommit

I am doing a batch update into my DB table using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate`, but I would like to disable `auto-commit` and perform the commit manually.

I can set auto-commit mode off from the `connection` object, but not sure how to do the same using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` object.

Comment: You should never work in auto-commit mode anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done my implementation using [TransactionTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html)

It has an `execute` method and I do the business logic inside a callback in this function.

```
transTemplate.execute( new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult()
        {       
                @Override
                protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult( TransactionStatus status)
                {
                    status.setRollbackOnly();
                    //business logic
                }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are aware of the transactional management in Spring where by defining `@Transactional` and passing metadata of `Propagation` and `Isolation` you can elegantly manage transactions. If not take a look at the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html). In most cases that's all you need.

If you want to get transaction management at your own hands and fine-tune it (aka perform commit and rollbacks at will) you have to get the underlying *TransactionManager* directly.

Quoting from the [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html):

*Using the PlatformTransactionManager*

*You can also use the `org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager` directly to manage your transaction. Simply pass the implementation of the `PlatformTransactionManager` you are using to your bean through a bean reference. Then, using the `TransactionDefinition` and `TransactionStatus` objects you can initiate transactions, roll back, and commit.*

```
DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
// explicitly setting the transaction name is something that can only be done programmatically
def.setName("SomeTxName");
def.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED);

TransactionStatus status = txManager.getTransaction(def);
try {
  // execute your business logic here
}
catch (MyException ex) {
  txManager.rollback(status);
  throw ex;
}
txManager.commit(status);
```

Comment: Thanks, just one quick feedback, where is TransactionDefinition defined?

Comment: One other question, for the business logic I am going to use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate that uses the same datasource I used to create DataSourceTransactionManager. Will the two be able to interact with each other, that is refer to same DB connection?

Comment: The full names are: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition and org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus. If you are pulling dependencies using Maven that's the dependency coordinates: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Exactly thats the one: DataSourceTransactionManager. All you have to do is inject it in the Bean you are to do these operations. Underneath NamedParameterJdbcTemplate is using it too and if you inject it in your bean you'll get the control of it and being able to use the finetuned TransactionDefinition and TransactionStatus.

Comment: A bit of novice and silly question at this stage, by injecting, do you mean pass as parameter during construction, just like below?
 new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
 new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);

Comment: I have a feeling you don't need all this. @Transactional should be sufficient if you annotate your Service method that is calling your DAO where your jdbcTemplate is used for your CRUD operations. I would suggest have a quick read through the doc: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html and google for sample examples.