# Hibernate and Mysql, transaction autocommit just for a section

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, transactions

I need to deny the transaction rollback for a little piece of a method, and I don't know how to do it because in other part of method I need the standard behaviour.

This is my Spring, Hibernate configuration:

```
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

And my class is declared with a "@Transaction" annotation to open the transaction and rollback in case of Exception.
However I need to force the commit after an important insertion on db. How to do this?

This is the example code:

```
@Transactional
public void myMethod(Object obj){
   check.do();
   check.control();
   try{
      dao.insert(obj);
      fileWriter.write();
      printer.print();
   }catch(Exception e){
      log.error(e);
   }
}
```

What I do inside the try statement (dao.insert) must be in autocommit because I don't want that something after the insert rollbacks the transaction. In my example, if the printer.print() fails I don't want that the dao.insert() rollbacks. However I need this behaviour only inside this try.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I also tried to remote @Transactional annotation and createa a private transactional method just for the dao.insert, how ever tt fails all lazy load of entities inside other components (ex. printer.print() and so on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was:

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor=Exception.class)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can achieve it through any API or configuration in hibernate. The only approcah I can think is to break your method in multiple method and set @Transactional on only what is required.

Comment: But If I did not set @Transactional in the method is the transaction automatically started or I should start it manually?

Comment: I tried it and without @Transactional i get "could not initialize proxy - no Session"

Answer (score 1):

Inject the `transactionManager` to your bean of that method and perform `commit`/`rollback` whenever required through it. Have a look at [my answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842852/disabling-auto-commit-in-namedparameterjdbctemplate-batchupdate/16843350#16843350).

Comment: It may solve but i can not understand how to get the transaction...  I just get this bean: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager but how to get the current transaction opened by @Transactional annotation?